# The function $\varphi(u)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(f(x)+u\ g(x))$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f$ and $g$ two function bounded such that :
>   $$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$
>    Let : $$\varphi(u)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(f(x)+u\ g(x)),\quad u \in \mathbb{R}$$
>    Show that  $\varphi$ is Lipschitz continuous.

We have to show that

$$\forall(x,y)\in R^2,~|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|\le k~|x-y|.$$

$f$ and $g$ are two bounded function then $\exists M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall  x\in [0 ,1]$ we have $|f(x)| \leq M $ and $|g(x)| \leq M$.
Let $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$.
Let  $x\in [0,1]$. 
we have : $$f(x) + u.g(x) = f(x) + v.g(x) + (u -v)g(x)\leq  \varphi(v) + |u -v|.M$$

How can I goes to $\sup$ to say :

$$\varphi(u)\leq \varphi(v) + |u-v|.M$$.

**Edit :**

is that because of $f,g$ are bounded over compact $[0,1]$ then supremum of $f(x) + u.g(x)$ exists. but the problem is that $\sqrt{x}$ is bounded over compact $[0,1]$ and  see this [$\sqrt{x}$ isn't Lipschitz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667346/sqrtx-isnt-lipschitz-function)

Comment: What do you mean with "sup" of a constant in the definition of $\varphi$? Also,$f,g$ are only defined on $[0,1]$, but it seems as if you are plugging in arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: Can you specify over what set the supremum is over? If it is over $u \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\phi$ should not depend on $u$.

Comment: @PhoemueX it was just typo why you didn't fix it

Comment: @SRX  i just forget to add supremum over $[0,1]$

Comment: It was honestly not clear to me what you were asking. If you had written $x$ and $u$ instead of just $u$, I might have guessed. Now the question looks fine.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank You for Your Reviews

Answer (score 3):

Notational confusion nonwithstanding, it is clear from the proof you began that the function you consider is 
$$\varphi(u)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(f(x)+u\ g(x)),\quad u \in \mathbb{R}$$
Following what you already did, let $M=\sup_{[0,1]}|g|$ (no need to worry about $f$). Fix $u$ and $v$ and note that for all $x\in [0,1]$
$$
f(x)+u\ g(x) \le (f(x)+v\ g(x))+M|u-v| \le \varphi(v)+M|u-v| \tag{1}
$$
Formula (1) says that the number $\varphi(v)+M|u-v|$ is an upper bound for the set  $\{f(x)+u\ g(x):x\in[0,1]\}$. The supremum, by definition, is the *least* upper bound. Hence,
$$
\varphi(u)\le \varphi(v)+M|u-v| \tag{2}
$$
Repeat the above with $u,v$ interchanged to get
$$
\varphi(v)\le \varphi(u)+M|u-v| \tag{3}
$$
Finally, combine (2) and (3) to obtain
$$
|\varphi(u)- \varphi(v)|\le M|u-v| \tag{4}
$$

Comment: we have that $M=\sup_{[0,1]}|g|$ since g  is bounded over $[0,1]$ and you add $|.|$ because we don't know if g is increasing or decreasing am i right

Comment: Yes, the supremum is finite because a continuous function on $[0,1]$ is bounded. I put absolute value because   $g$ could take  positive or negative values. It does not matter if it's increasing or decreasing.

Comment: they said only that are bounded over compact not continuous how did you know they are continuous

Comment: Okay, they are bounded and that's the only thing I used. Forget that I said "continuous".

Comment: but can we say that they are continuous

Comment: why would it be the same $x$ that gives sup for $u$ and $v$

Comment: We can say they are continuous, but it would be a wrong thing to say. Also, nobody said the same $x$ would give $\sup$ for both $u$ and $v$. Also, this is my last comment here.