# Prove or disprove that there exists $K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K |x-y|,\;\forall\;\;x,y\in[0,1],$ edited version.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a function on $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb{R}$. Suppose that if $x\in[0,1],$ there exists $K_x$ such that \begin{align}|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K_x |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;y\in[0,1].\end{align}
Prove or disprove that there exists $K$ such that \begin{align}|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K |x-y|,\;\forall\;\;x,y\in[0,1].\end{align}

**DISPROOF**

Consider the function \begin{align} f:[0&,1]\to 
\Bbb{R},  \\&x\mapsto \sqrt{x} \end{align}

Let $x=0$ and $y\in (0,1]$ be fixed. Then,
\begin{align} \left| f(0)-f(y) \right|&=\left|0-\sqrt{y}  \right|   \end{align}
Take $y=1/(4n^2)$ for all $n.$ Then,
\begin{align} \left| f(0)-f\left(\dfrac{1}{4n^2}\right) \right|&=\left|0-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2}}  \right| \\&=2n^{3/2}\left|\dfrac{1}{4n^2} -0 \right|   \end{align}
By assumption, there exists $K_0$ such that 
\begin{align} \left| f(0)-f\left(\dfrac{1}{4n^2}\right) \right|&=2n^{3/2}\left|\dfrac{1}{4n^2} -0 \right|\leq K_0\left|\dfrac{1}{4n^2} -0 \right|   \end{align}
Sending $n\to\infty,$ we have
\begin{align} \infty \leq K_0<\infty,\;\;\text{contradiction}.  \end{align}
Hence, the function $f$ is not Lipschitz in $[0,1]$.

**QUESTION:** Is my disproof correct?

Comment: I would suggest that before you start the computation you actually write explicitly the claim whose truth you need to decide. Is $f$ supposed to be continuous? Are there any other assumptions? Once that is explicit, say what you are going to do: "We will show that the statement fails in general by providing a counterexample. Note that it is enough to show that there is a differentiable $f$ with unbounded derivative, because ..." Only after you've done that, proceed with your counterexample. People don't want to put up with a wall of symbols if they don't know its purpose.

Comment: It would be much simpler to just define $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}.$ There is no need for a piecewise definition.

Comment: Nice proof, but you forgot to mention the question. I assume the question was: if $f$ is continuous, then prove that there exists $K$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le K |x - y|$ for all $x, y$, or else find a counterexample $f$.

Comment: Also, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$. So you should say that $f|_{(0,1)}$ is differentiable but the derivative is unbounded, thus a constant $K$ cannot exist for $f|_{(0,1)}$, thus a constant $K$ cannot exist for $f$ either.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/667346/81360)

Comment: "Anyway, I've still not found anyone to tell if my disproof is correct. " Huh??? As eplained quite clearly below, your disproof is wrong. Because if $f=\sqrt t$ then there does not exist $K_0$ such that $|f(0)-f(y)|\le K_0|0-y|$ for all $y$.

Comment: In fact you state explicitly that there is no such $K_0$. So this makes no  sense at all! The existence of $K_0$ is  a _hypothesis_ - to give a counterexample you need an $f$ where the hypothesis is _true_. Showing that $K_0$ does not exist, as you do, shows that $\sqrt t$ is simply irrelevant.

Comment: You edited your question again! Now it seems that you did not try anything. Please restore here the original question, otherwise it will be closed!

Comment: @Mike Please restore the original question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the function $f$ is not Lipschitz in $[0,1]$, but your argument should be modified. You may simply say that
$$\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}-0}=\sqrt{n}\to +\infty$$
which contradicts the fact that $|f(x)-f(y)|/|x-y|$ is bounded by a constant $K$.

On the other hand this is not a counterexample for your statement. For the same reason as above (Just take $y=1/n$), for $x=0$ there is no constant $K_0$ such that
$$|f(0)-f(y)|\leq K_0 |0-y|,\;\;\forall y\in[0,1].$$
Instead consider the function
$$f(x)=\cases{x\sin(1/x)& if $x\not=0$\\0& if $x=0$,}$$
If $x_n=1/(2\pi n)$ and $y_n=1/(2\pi n+\pi/2)$.
then  $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|/|x_n-y_n|$ is unbounded which implies that $f$ is not Lipschitz in $[0,1]$, but for any $x\in[0,1],$ there exists $K_x$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K_x |x-y|,\;\;\forall\;\;y\in[0,1].$$
In fact take $K_0=1$ and for $x\in(0,1]$ the existence of $K_x$ follows from
$f'\in C^1((0,1])$.

Comment: @Mike I added a few lines. Your disproof is incorrect.

Comment: You might mention _why_ the correct counterexample _does_ satisfy the hypothesis. (If $f$ is differentiable at $$ then $K_x$ exists...)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't incorrect per se, but its unnecessarily convoluted.  To show that $f'$ is unbounded, just observe that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ so that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\infty$.  Hence, $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$, which is precisely what you want to prove.  That's all you need to say.

The last part is a little hand-wavy though.  Technically, you should say something like this:  $f$ is Lipschitz on $[\epsilon,1]$ with constant $K_\epsilon:=\sup_{\epsilon\leq x\leq 1}|f'(x)|$.  Since $K_\epsilon\to\infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0^+$, $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[0,1]$.

Better still just to do an explicit calculation, as the other fellow did.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben W! I really learnt a lot from you! Kindly check my post, I edited it! (+1)